# PHP Search in array for a string do not need an exact match

Tags: php

I have tried to Google this but can only get examples for exact matches in an array or character searches.

My question is. I have two arrays one will be an array of loan numbers. 
The second will be an array of Pdf files in a folder. For demonstration purposes, I have hardcoded the file names into an array. 
How do I search an array for a string which is not an exact match?
If this is not possible is there another approach?

I have tried to use a set of substring function to get the loan number but as the loan number is the dynamic length it is not a valid option.

Below is an example of what my arrays will be like

```
<?php

$Csv_array=array();
$Folder_array = array();

$line_number = false;


array_push($Csv_array,'234234','45454','78797');




array_push($Folder_array,'723325_Test_letter.pdf','753434_Test_letter.pdf','75443434_Test_letter.pdf');



?>
```

Comment: Is there likely to be a partial (sub-string) match? e.g. the "_Test_letter" part? If so you can use `preg_match()` for that.

Comment: The start of the letter will be the match example Loan number ':723325' Pdf will be  '723325_Test_letter.pdf so the first  x amount of letters will match

Comment: what's your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match()` I expect.

e.g.

```
<?php
$folders = ['723325_Test_letter.pdf','753434_Test_letter.pdf','75443434_Test_letter.pdf'];

foreach ($folders as $folder) {
    if (preg_match('/(.*)_Test_letter\.pdf/', $folder, $matches)) {
        echo "Invoice number {$matches[1]}\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Invoice number 723325
Invoice number 753434
Invoice number 75443434
```

Does that help?